# Have a switching power adapter that came with my karaoke machine, it only has two prongs, it says 100-240~50-60Hz 1.5A, can I plug into 120v outlet

Tags: electrical

Have a switching power adapter that came with my karaoke machine.  It’s 100-240v~ 50-60Hz 1.5A, can I plug this into a 120v outlet?  It says insert AC power cord into an AC outlet having 230v, 50Hz

Comment: It may be a 2-part device, where one part is "universal" and the other part specific to a particular plug type. Can you add some pictures?

Comment: Does it have any more instructions?  So far it seems like it has an input of 230v 50Hz but maybe a range of outputs(seems odd), would figure the opposite.

Comment: UL would not let it be built with the wrong plug, so the unit is not UL Listed and was not legal to sell in the US.  Sounds like more 3rd party direct mail sellers, e.g. ebay, amazon marketplace etc.  Send it back with a vengeance.

Comment: Perhaps the Karaoke machine instructions were written earlier for a 230V PSU but it was shipped with a universal one.  If the PSU itself says 100-240V on its label I would go with that.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it has nothing to do with DIY Home Improvement.

Answer (score 3):

That is called a universal adapter usually the ones sold in the US have 2 parallel blades, the ones in other areas may be 2 round pins. As long as they are correct for the receptacle the power supply will work through the entire voltage range. A photo of the connector would be helpful but if it looks normal the answer is yes if it looks odd there is normally an adapter

Comment: Are you also thinking very bad translation of the instructions?

Comment: @crip659 the fact that the OP could understand the voltages and frequency’s it sounds like a great translation, OR would you be wanting to place blades in holes that object (note yes this was similar to a translation to a similar us to Japanese supply I purchased in Japan) if I remember correctly I needed a 90v adapter for my 120v computer supply purchased in the US but made in Japan for HP. So if it matches our receptacles it will work.